# Titanium - iOS equivalent for Menu/MenuItem?

Tags: javascript, titanium, appcelerator, titanium-alloy

I am developing in Appcelerator, and I have looked through the documentation and have not been able to find a menu element for iOS devices. Even if it's just a single button an a pop up dialog comes up that would be fine too. Is there a way to add a button to the far right of the navigation bar that says "Options"? It's for a messaging feature, so I will have options like "Select" and "Delete".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For iOS there are the `Window` properties [LeftNavButtons](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.Window-property-leftNavButtons) and [LeftNavButton](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.Window-property-leftNavButton) and of course also the Right equivalent.

Don't try to use them the same as you try on Android, they're completely different. The UX meant for these buttons is also different. But since you can just put an icon/button there and watch for click event what you do after is up to you.

Look into the [Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/overview/design-principles/) from Apple for more info on how to properly implement UI/UX on iOS